# How to use azure translator with authorization token?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator

I want to use azure translator service with the Authorization token. There are plenty of resources explaining how to do it with subscription key but I could not found any resource explaining the use of authorization token. I can get the authorization token but when I send a request with it, the response status code is 401.
This is how I send the request:

```sh
curl POST 'https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0&to=es' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer token' \
--data-raw '[{'\''Text'\'':'\''Hello World!'\''}]'
```

Comment: Please avoid sharing code as image. Instead paste the properly formatted code. Thanks.

Comment: I think the SDK is expecting the Subscription Key: https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/Text-Translation-API-V3-NodeJS/blob/master/Translate.js

Comment: I do not think so as it is described in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-reference

Comment: That sort of looks right (in my version of curl you have to say, `-X POST` rather than just `POST`). You should check your token.

Comment: Dear I do not think that the problem was that because I tried with their SDK too (https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/Text-Translation-API-V3-NodeJS/blob/master/Translate.js) and same thing occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call Text Translation API with authentication token, please refer to the following steps

1. Get a token. If your service is global, the endpoint is `https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken`

```
curl -v -X POST \
"https://YOUR-REGION.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken" \
-H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-H "Content-length: 0" \
-H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY"
```

Besides, please note that an authentication token is valid for 10 minutes. The token should be reused when making multiple calls to the Translator. However, if your program makes requests to the Translator over an extended period of time, then your program must request a new access token at regular intervals (for example, every 8 minutes).

2. Call API

```
curl -X POST 'https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0&from=en&to=de' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '[{ "text": "How much for the cup of coffee?" }]' | json_pp
```

[image]
[image]

For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/authentication?tabs=powershell#authenticate-with-an-authentication-token) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-reference#authenticating-with-an-access-token).